# Canvas and top navigation bar in facebook

Tags: facebook

Two simple facebook developer questions that seems impossible to google
1) 
Can I have a canvas (which is basically an iframe to my own web page, I hope) on a group page.

I want to add extra functionality on my fb-group. (As an example, if I had
a movie group I would like every user to be able to have a top 10-list, that is visible for all other group members)

2)
Can I have the facebook top navigation bar (including notifications)
on my own web page? I have seen it done.. .but it might be so that its not possible anymore?

Comment: 1) No. 2) Also No.

Comment: about 2) of course you can program it on your own. but i don´t think it´s a good idea, why would you want your website nav to look like facebook? i am sure they don´t want that either.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply.  @Broe, If you want the credits, please create an answer (instead of a comment) so I can set your answer as "correct" .But I will wait a bit to see if I get some more answers or possibly workaround to achieve similar result